# Resignment feedback

Tags: feedback

Some background: after the last year and a half I’ve discovered that difficult/demanding tasks has been unfairly distributed, meaning that I’ve been assigned a majority of these tasks (all employees have equal competence). It reached a point where I was nearly burned out.

Since then I have respectfully tried addressing my boss’ way of distributing tasks, and besides minor adjustments I realize six months later that the problem at large still persists. I consider this as a cue to finally take the step starting my own business, and therefore I’ve asked for my resignment.

Here’s my dilemma: I’ve become tired being the one addressing problems, so my goal is to leave on a high note, even though I still feel thrown under the bus from last year. On the other hand, my boss has now asked for feedback as a general routine when employees quit. Giving honest feedback would most likely rub him the wrong way as I am very critical to his ways.

I also feel that I have little interest in putting effort into formulating more constructive feedback than I’ve already done during this spring. At this point, i consider his shortcomings his responsibility, not mine.

Would it put leaving on a high note at risk if I tactfully decline giving feedback?

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, OP is asking a specific question about 'declining' giving feedback, the other is asking 'what' feedback to give, similar but not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "resignment"? It seems you're leaving your job (resigning), but sometimes it seems you're talking about being put on a different task (being reassigned). Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Would it put leaving on a high note at risk if I tactfully decline giving feedback?

Yes it would, it implies they would not like what they would hear.

There is no good reason to give anything other than generic platitudinous feedback in an exit interview. There is no personal benefit in it. And there are potential drawbacks which you already imagine.

If you're starting your own business and may eventually be a competitor it makes even less sense. If they want to mismanage, great, carry on the good work. I frequently praise an CEO I used to work under, without her my business would not have grown as fast and as solidly as it did. Half her biggest clients followed me out the door.

Comment: It's pretty common for people to want to take a dig on the way out, you have already recognised the potential pitfalls so I'm not telling you anything new really. Perhaps just solidifying it a bit from another point of view.

Comment: I appreciate that you recognize my reflections. Solidifying also helps!

Comment: @Erik if you want a simple, direct, and honest answer, Kilisi will provide it.

Comment: @Kilisi this is why I admire you man. You're a cold blooded, Machiavellian mother ****er

Answer (score 2):

> Would it put leaving on a high note at risk if I tactfully decline
>   giving feedback?

You have indicated that you know honest feedback would rub your boss the wrong way. So if your goal is to leave on a high note, you need to finesse the feedback.

Something like "I really liked working here, but this is an opportunity I couldn't turn down" would likely be appropriate.

Most exit interviews are just formalities anyway. Even though they ask for honest feedback, HR seldom really cares if you are giving an honest answer - it's just something they are required to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you should give feedback if asked. Refusing is unprofessional
2. If you are not comfortable sharing real feedback, you can always give a bunch of "catch all" phrases. "Exciting new opportunity", "want a change of role/career/industry/location", etc.
3. You can actually give constructive feedback, but it's best done in "I" sentences without judging or blaming. "I feel, that the work distribution wasn't optimal", "the way tasks are distributed is not intuitive to me and so I feel I need a place where I'm more in the loop with decision making"

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just to make clear, i never considered refusing an alternative.